# long running request processing is terminated on the ISP IIS server but runs to completion on local IIS in debug

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have this ASP.NET code that runs well on my local IIS, but not on on  the ISP's IIS. On Local IIS it executes to completion, and the whole picture archive is downloaded without issues.

When run at the ISP, the download ends prematurely after 1 or 2, sometimes even 10 minutes, and only first 20, 50, or 100 MB are downloaded of the 300MB ZIP archive.

What is the issue here? Could it be some configuration parameter, that I can call  them and ask to change ?

(For ZIP I am using Ionic.Zip, and FlickrNet for flickr)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsLoggedIn())
        Response.Redirect("/login.aspx");
    else
    {
        // this is dco album id, find out what photosetId it maps to
        string albumId = Request.Params["id"];
        bool downloadOriginal = ((string)Request.Params["ori"]) == "1";
        Album album = findAlbum(new Guid(albumId));
        Flickr flickr = FlickrInstance();
        PhotosetPhotoCollection photos = flickr.PhotosetsGetPhotos(album.PhotosetId, PhotoSearchExtras.OriginalUrl | PhotoSearchExtras.Large2048Url | PhotoSearchExtras.Large1600Url);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = false;

        // ascii only
        //string archiveName = album.Title + ".zip";
        string archiveName = "photos.zip";
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + archiveName);
        int picCount = 0;
        string picNamePref = album.PhotosetId.Substring(album.PhotosetId.Length - 6);
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.None;
            zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.None;
            zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;
            _map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (Photo p in photos)
            {
                string pictureUrl = null;
                if (downloadOriginal)
                {
                    pictureUrl = p.OriginalUrl;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureUrl))
                        pictureUrl = p.Large2048Url;
                }
                else
                {
                    pictureUrl = p.Large2048Url;
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureUrl))
                    pictureUrl = p.Large1600Url;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureUrl))
                    pictureUrl = p.LargeUrl;

                string pictureName = picNamePref + "_" + (++picCount).ToString("000") + ".jpg";
                _map.Add(pictureName, pictureUrl);
                zip.AddEntry(pictureName, processPicture);
            }
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.End();
    }
}
private volatile Dictionary<string, string> _map;
protected void processPicture(string pictureName, Stream output)
{
    // the pic is attempted to be retrieved multiple number of times because of the gateway timeout error
    // that flickr gives sometimes
    //
    // If all attempts fail, the exception is ignored, an empty entry is written to the archive,
    // and we move on to the next entry
    //
    // Exception cannot be allowed to propagate to the caller.
    // If it does, the archive will be corrupted, and the user will see "Unexpected end of archive" message when trying to open the archive
    int numberOfAttempts = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAttempts; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(_map[pictureName]);
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream input = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[8092];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = input.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
                        output.Write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                output.Flush();
            }
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception exep)
        {
            // TODO: got no logging
            //string message = exep.Message;
            //string stackTrace = exep.StackTrace;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try adding logging for each step to isolate where the problem is. Since it's so erratic, could be a connectivity issue to Flickr from your ISP or an uncaught error. Likely not an IIS setting though.

Comment: Added tracing to the code with messages in all major points, also put the whole Page_Load piece inside try-catch to see what kind of exception happens there. The tracing worked well when everything was going well. But on ISP server, right after the download completes, the one that gives truncated archive, the application trace is **empty**, so something serious happens on the server that clears even the application trace log. The session stays, I am still logged in, and can click the link again. Weird.. Thank you for your help. Logging was a good idea.